# How to fix error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in Cell.php

Tags: php, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I've deployed my laravel source which integrated maatwebsite package inside, i have some export excel in my project. It works fine in the xampp localhost, but when i deploy it to the virtual server, it always return error:

```
message: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='"
exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
file: "/var/www/src/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Cell.php"
line: 517
```

I set up php7.1 and my require composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"
    }
```

Someone can tell me how to fix this problem???

Comment: [Symmetric array destructuring](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php#migration71.new-features.symmetric-array-destructuring) is a PHP 7.1 feature. Your server is probably running PHP 7.0

Comment: @Symmetric array destructuring: i used command php -i then it show php7.1.33

Comment: Are you running `php -i` on your server? It may have multiple PHP instances installed and the CLI is using a different version to FPM / mod-php. Easiest way to check is add a `info.php` file with `<?php phpinfo();` and check it online

Comment: @Phil: i've run that command and it tell me php7.1.33

Comment: Was that from a file with `phpinfo()` run through your HTTP server?

Comment: I tried to uninstalled php and re-install, now it's work :D

Answer (score 1):

edit the cell.php file, in my case the path is vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Cell/Cell.php becasuse i used composer to install and search this function

```
public function setValue($value, ?IValueBinder $binder = null): self
    {
        $binder ??= self::getValueBinder();
        if (!$binder->bindValue($this, $value)) {
            throw new Exception('Value could not be bound to cell.');
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

in this line delete '??' `$binder ??= self::getValueBinder();` to
`$binder = self::getValueBinder();`

this work for me, bye

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

don't use `=` in composer, you should use `^` or `~`

The full explanation is at [Tilde Version Range (~)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#tilde-version-range-) and [Caret Version Range (^)](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-)

> The ~ operator is best explained by example: ~1.2 is equivalent to >=1.2 <2.0.0, while ~1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3 <1.3.0. As you can see it is mostly useful for projects respecting semantic versioning.
>
> The ^ operator behaves very similarly but it sticks closer to semantic versioning, and will always allow non-breaking updates. For example ^1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3 <2.0.0 as none of the releases until 2.0 should break backwards compatibility. For pre-1.0 versions it also acts with safety in mind and treats ^0.3 as >=0.3.0 <0.4.0.

Comment: The problem is in Cell.php not in composer.json

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone...

My case was with NGINX configuration for the online server.

My Nginx server block was set to PHP 7.2 fpm while the application was running on PHP 7.4

So I:-

1. Edited the server block located at ***/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com***
2. Restarted php fpm

> sudo service php7.4-fpm restart

3. Restarted nginx

> sudo systemctl reload nginx

This solved my problem after countless trials